# Synchronize two methods in different classes (and different packages)

Tags: java, synchronization

I'm facing an issue regarding Java method synchronization. Let's hope I can explain it briefly:

I have two different methods in two different classes, in two different packages. Something like:

```
Package1
     |_Class1
            \MethodA

Package2
     |_Class2
            \MethodB
```

Ok, so now I need to synchronize these two methods, which are **not threads**. So far, I have two different approaches:

***Shared semaphore***.

Create a shared static semaphore outside `Package1` and `Package2`, something like:

```
 package Package3;

 public class SemaphoreClass {

    public static Semaphore;

}
```

I don't really know if JVM would consider this a shared semaphore, anyway.

***Synchronized (SharedClass.class)***.

Using a shared class to synchronize those two methods, something like:

```
 public void MethodA() {
        synchronized (SharedClass.class) {
           //...
        }
```

and

```
public void MethodB() {
        synchronized (SharedClass.class) {
           //...
        }
```

Anyway, these are just approaches. I would like to hear what's the best way to implement what I'm trying to achieve. Having a shared semaphore for JVM would make things easier, but well, I know there must be a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The semaphore solution is fine... Don't forget however to release it in a `finally` block!

Comment: The fact that classes are in different packages is not relevant, you can synchronize its instances the same way that you would synchronize instances of a single class.

Comment: @SJuan76 I know it's not really relevant, that's why I put them inside the "( )" ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of your approaches should work, but I don't think locking on class is a recommended practices. Prefer locking on instances of `Object`, or use proper locks from `java.util`. Also, do not lock on `String`.

Alternatively, you could let instances of classes `Class1` and `Class2` can take a lock as parameter during instantiation:

```
   class Class1 {
        private final Object lock;
        public Class1( Object lock ) { this.lock = lock }
        public method() { synchronize( lock ) { } );
   }
```

Then make sure that you create *one* lock (with `new Object()`) and pass it to the two instances of `Class1` and `Class2`.

So basically, you've broken down the original problem in two: 1) the two classes do no share anything statically global, they just receive a parameter. 2) the clients of `Class1` and `Class2` must pass the correct lock. The client of `Class1` and `Class2` acts as the "orchestrator".